# checkbox not changing variable on deactivation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkbox that is designed like a on/off switch in CSS. When I activate this switch the a script would run that turns a vaible on and sets it to the body. When I try to deactivate it nothing happens other then the switch moving to the oof position

script:

```
    function checkDarkMode () {
    if (localStorage.darkMode) {
        document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    }
}

    function toggleDarkMode () {
        localStorage.darkMode = !(localStorage.darkMode);
        checkDarkMode();
    }
```

HTML code of switch:

```
<div class="onoffswitch" style="position: fixed;left: 88%;top: 4%;">
    <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="onoffswitch"
    id="myonoffswitch"
    class="onoffswitch-checkbox"
    onclick="toggleDarkMode()"
    />
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I am having two problems with this switch
When I deactivate this switch the lever will move to its off position but the script wont be ran or even remove the `class='dark-mode'` from the body of the page.

The second problem is when I go to another hyperlinked page the witch isnt in the on position if the script was ran on another page.But the dark mode theme is applied to the page. How would I be able to get the script to be ran and deactivate the dark mode theme from the body. Is there any way to apply the same variable used in the script to actiavte and deactivate the dar-mode to the actual switch so that it can check if the switch should be on the on or off position across pages.

Comment: When I open up console in the browser I can add and remove the "dark-mode" from body without using the switch. Does this mean that the switch isnt calling the functions?